# Visualizing the level sets for this function

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $F: T^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) \mapsto x_{2}$. Recall that $$T^{2} = \{(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) : \left(\sqrt{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}} - R \right)^{2} + x_{3}^{2} = r^{2}\}$$

I am being asked to identify the shapes of the level sets $F^{-1}(c)$ for $c$ a singular value, but I am a bit unclear as to what a singular value is in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're slicing $T^2$ by planes $x_2=\text{constant}=c$. Any time this plane is tangent to the surface, $c$ is a singular value. You should find $4$ such values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I go about solving for such singular values, and is there a way to visualize/describe the level sets corresponding to these singular values (and regular values, as well)?

Comment: Draw the torus and draw slices! The computation is: The normal vector of a level surface $f=C$ is given by $\nabla f$. When is this parallel to $(0,1,0)$?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but I'm very rusty on multivariable calculus. From what I understand, this approach entails viewing the 2-torus itself as a level set $G(x,y,z) = r^{2}$? So it would be the gradient of this function defining the torus (as shown in the question statement)?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Warm up on a simple sphere if you want to reassure yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction with this. If we define $G(x,y,z) = \left( \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} - R \right)^{2} + z^{2}$ and view the 2-torus as a level set $G(x,y,z) = r^{2}$, then I calculated:

$$\nabla{G} = \left(x \left(2 - \frac{2R}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}} \right), y \left(2 - \frac{2R}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}} \right), 2z \right)$$

Then $\nabla{G}(0,1,0) = (0, 2-2R, 0)$.

Either I've done something wrong or I just don't know how to proceed.

Comment: No, no, you want to know when (i.e., for what $(x,y,z)$) $\nabla G(x,y,z)$ is *parallel* to $(0,1,0)$.

Comment: So after seeking some help with this multivariable calculus aspect of the problem, I have determined that the set of vectors parallel to $(0,1,0)$ is the set $(0, k, 0)$ for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

At this point, after determining $x = 0 = z$, we're left with solving $(y - R)^{2} = r^{2}$ and solving for $y$... which gives two possibilities: $y = R - r$ and $y = R + r$.

Am I completely off-base?

Comment: Plus or minus. Those give you the $4$ critical points I told you to expect. What are the cross-sections $x_2=c$ Of the torus for these four?

Comment: Thanks, that was quite the learning experience.

Now, I suppose you're asking about the cross-sections to motivate how the level sets look? To clarify first, cross-section refers to the intersection of the torus with the plane $x_{2} = c$?

Comment: Yuppers. Get a doughnut and slice ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It really cleared up a lot of things for me. I'm still struggling a little bit with the visualization of the level sets, but since it might be kind of hard to explain what they look like, I suppose I'll have to work it out myself.

Other than that, I would just like to clarify that the regular values for this function will be all points on the torus were $x \neq 0, y \neq 0, z \neq 0$?

I'm very thankful for your help, so if this is asking too much, I will just close the question as solved and keep at it.

Comment: The regular *values* are all $c$ other than $\pm(R\pm r)$. And what you should see is that when you slice with such planes $x_2=c$, you get either the empty set or a smooth curve. (Values live in the range of the function, not the domain.)